# On a NTFS drive mounted with NTFS-3G with user mapping file present, all new files belong to root

Tags: linux, ntfs-3g

On my system, I have a large NTFS-formatted data partition, which is shared between Linux (Debian 8) and Windows (2012 Server). When I created a user-mapping file, as described in the NTFS-3G documentation, most file permissions worked as expected, only any new files created by me on Linux on the NTFS partition are owned by root and uneditable by my normal user account:

```
$ pwd
/mnt/data/src
$ ls -l 
total 0
$ touch file
touch: setting times of ‘file’: Permission denied
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 28 10:41 file
$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x 1 ##### root 144 Apr 28 10:41 .
$ id
uid=1000(#####) gid=1(daemon) groups=1(daemon),4(adm),20(dialout),21(fax),24(cdrom),25(floppy),26(tape),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev),110(lpadmin),113(scanner)
```

How should I set it that files are created as normally, with ownership set to my unprivileged user account? I tried setting the inherit mount option, but then I ran into another problem, namely that I couldn't write into root-owned directories and neither chmod or chown as root had any effect at all

Relevant files:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdf1 during installation
UUID=eab88331-a1c7-4f18-b971-ad5f58c6d08c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sde2 during installation
UUID=188C-66A1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdf2 during installation
UUID=1d82108c-20bb-4df2-8df4-2ca145cca01f /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdf5 during installation
UUID=8e94b87a-e170-4a34-88fe-2100e8db0ae6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0

UUID=592AF2FB029E1E67 /mnt/data ntfs-3g
```

.

```
$ sudo cat /mnt/data/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping
[sudo] password for #####: 
# Generated by usermap for Linux, v 1.1.6
:#####:S-1-5-21-742487409-2243251135-2122958030-513
:#####:S-1-5-21-1202660629-1788223648-1801674531-513
:#####:S-1-5-21-343818398-1004336348-725345543-513
:#####:S-1-5-21-1801674531-1614895754-1417001333-513
:#####:S-1-5-21-117609710-2025429265-839522115-513
#####:#####:S-1-5-21-742487409-2243251135-2122958030-1003
#####:#####:S-1-5-21-1202660629-1788223648-1801674531-1004
#####:#####:S-1-5-21-343818398-1004336348-725345543-1004
#####:#####:S-1-5-21-1801674531-1614895754-1417001333-1004
#####:#####:S-1-5-21-117609710-2025429265-839522115-1004
#####:#####:S-1-5-21-117609710-2025429265-839522115-1005
```

Answer (score 1):

We just ran into this issue on my girlfriend's computer, though we went in with some more information: my user on the same machine could create files without issue.

After trying more than a few things we finally figured out what was wrong on her machine; her primary group was set to `sudo`, where mine was set to `users`

```
$ id y
```

> uid=1001(y) gid=100(users)
>
> groups=100(users),7(lp),91(video),92(audio),1000(sudo)

```
$ id x
```

> uid=1000(x) gid=1000(sudo)
>
> groups=1000(sudo),7(lp),91(video),92(audio),100(users)

We followed the instructions [here](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/safely-change-primary-group-group-in-linux/) to change her default group to `users` unmounted the drive, logged out, logged back in, remounted the drive and everything started behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mount your `data` partition with the `permissions` option. Then you can change the owner of your files.

However, I think new files will not be mapped to the Windows user.